# All links changed from localhost/mysitename/blablabla to www.localhost/blablabla

Tags: redirect, local

My Drupal site was working fine locally. Then I don't know what happened to it. All links changed from localhost/mysitename/blablabla to www.localhost/blablabla. this means that www. appears before any address and mysitename is missing. I didn't change anything in .htaccess or php.ini.
I tested both **WampServer** and **Acuia Dev Desktop** as local servers, but no success. 
I should mention that I installed a module "jQuery Calendar" before getting this error, but I am not sure if this was the source of problem. Because I restored the database with my online backups (without that module) and removed the module folder from sites/modules. but no success at all.
Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found the source of problem. The module had a library in sites/libraries folder. I removed that and everything got on the right track. wish this helps someone in future :)